# Error : app failed to start several times

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to create an app by following a tutorial , I followed everything shown in tutorial , but when its time to run the app , the app shuts down without showing anythig,
the message i get is **app failed to start several times**

here is logcat file:

> 2021-10-11 12:08:46.199 21196-21229/com.example.newsfresh I/System.out: [okhttp]:check permission begin!
> 2021-10-11 12:08:46.200 21196-21229/com.example.newsfresh W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
> 2021-10-11 12:08:46.203 21196-21229/com.example.newsfresh I/System.out: [okhttp] e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaUtils
> 2021-10-11 12:08:46.211 21196-21229/com.example.newsfresh I/System.out: [socket]:check permission begin!
> 2021-10-11 12:08:46.211 21196-21229/com.example.newsfresh W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
> 2021-10-11 12:08:46.212 21196-21229/com.example.newsfresh I/System.out: [socket] e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaUtils
> 2021-10-11 12:08:46.223 21196-21196/com.example.newsfresh I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 21196 SIG: 9

the code for main activity is:`

```
package com.example.newsfresh

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NewsItemClicked {

    private  lateinit var madapter:NewsListAdapter
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

//        RecyclerView.LayoutManager=LinearLayoutManager
        recyclerView.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(this)
        fetchData()
        val adapter= NewsListAdapter(this)
        recyclerView.adapter=madapter

    }
    private  fun fetchData(){
        val url = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=In&category=business&apiKey=API_KEY"
        val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            { it ->
                val newsJsonArray =it.getJSONArray("articles")
                val newsArray =ArrayList<News>()
                for (i in 0 until newsJsonArray.length() ){
                    val newsJsonObject = newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                    val news = News(
                        newsJsonObject.getString("title"),
                        newsJsonObject.getString("author"),
                        newsJsonObject.getString("url"),
                        newsJsonObject.getString("urlToImage")
                    )
                    newsArray.add(news)
                }
               madapter.updateNews(newsArray)
            },
            { error ->
                // TODO: Handle error
            }
        )

// Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
        MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest)
    }

    override fun onItemClicked(item: News) {

    }
}`
```

here goes my adapter class code:`

```
package com.example.newsfresh

import android.os.Parcel
import android.os.Parcelable
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class NewsListAdapter(private val listener:NewsItemClicked) :RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsViewHolder>() {
    private val items:ArrayList<News> = ArrayList()
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NewsViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_news,parent,false)
        val viewHolder = NewsViewHolder(view)
        view.setOnClickListener {
             listener.onItemClicked(items[viewHolder.adapterPosition])
        }
        return viewHolder
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NewsViewHolder, position: Int) {
         val currentItem = items[position]
        holder.titleView.text=currentItem.title
    }

    fun updateNews(updatedNews:ArrayList<News>){
        items.clear()
        items.addAll(updatedNews)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {

        return items.size
    }

}


class NewsViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val titleView:TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title)
}

interface  NewsItemClicked{
    fun onItemClicked(item:News)
}`
```

Comment: 99% you don't have permission in your manifest file. Something like this -  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: I have already given the permission still don't work

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on these

- Check if you have INTERNET permission in your manifest file.
  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
- Check if you are doing the network request on the main thread.

Update

- Check if you have ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission.
  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Comment: i already had these , still don't work,what should  i  do now?